# communication between activities without launching the second one

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a fragment that contains a checkbox, this fragment is related to an activity configActivity. I was able to retrieve the state of the checkbox in the activity. 
I want to retrieve this state from another activity (the Main activity) when the app is launched.
I've tried this method but with the OnActivityResult i get a nullpointer and i have to launch the other activity for it to work.

This is my fragment:

```
public class configFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
CheckBox check;
configActivity cmt;

OnChecked mCallback;



public interface OnChecked {
     void Oncheck(Boolean checkstatus);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.config_layout, container, false);
    check = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
    TextView text1=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    text1.setText("hello ");

   // cmt=(configActivity) getActivity();
    check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(check.isChecked()){
                mCallback.Oncheck(true);

            }else{
                Log.d("status","not checked");
              mCallback.Oncheck(false);
            }
        }
    });

    Boolean test=load();
    if(test){
        mCallback.Oncheck(true);
    }else{
        mCallback.Oncheck(false);
    }


    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    save(check.isChecked());
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    check.setChecked(load());

    Boolean test=load();
    if(test){
        mCallback.Oncheck(true);
    }else{
        mCallback.Oncheck(false);
    }
}

private void save(final boolean isChecked) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("check", isChecked);
    editor.commit();
}

public boolean load() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("check", check.isChecked());
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (OnChecked) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnChecked");
    }
}
```

This is my class :

```
public class configActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity implements configFragment.OnChecked {

public Boolean checking;

@Override
protected Fragment createFragment() {
    return new configFragment();
}




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // configFragment cf=new configFragment();





}


@Override
public void Oncheck(Boolean checkstatus) {
    if(checkstatus){
        checking=true;
        Log.d("status of checking",checking.toString());
    }else{
        checking=false;
        Log.d("status of checking",checking.toString());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("value",checking);
    setResult(2,intent);

}
}
```

And this is my main Activity where I want to retrieve the state of the checkbox:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public Boolean check;
public Boolean message;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView hello=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
    Button but1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


    but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,configActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            startActivityForResult(i,2);



        }
    });

    hello.setText("Hello world");



    if(message){
        Log.d("value of message",message.toString());
    }else{
        Log.d("value of message",message.toString());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2
    if(requestCode==2)
    {
         message=data.getExtras().getBoolean("value");

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Using Shared Preferences is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Shared preferences to store checkbox value and you can then retrieve it any time you want without actually having to launch config activity again.

You can store the checkbox value like this:

```
// cmt=(configActivity) getActivity();
check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("checkboxValue", check.isChecked());
        editor.commit();
    }
});
```

And then you can retrieve it any time in MainActivity like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean defaultValue = getResources().getBoolean("checkboxValue", false);
```

Comment: it gives me an error in the "getActivity" and the getBoolean since it needs an int not a string

Comment: Sorry, getBoolean needs a default value if entry is not found, I've put false in the post. And remove getActivity() from MainActivity code. It's a typo. I've updated the answer.

Comment: i tried your method : SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean defaultValue = sharedPref.getBoolean("checkboxvalue",false);      but i always retrieve it as false. even when it s true

Comment: It is impossible for getBoolean to expect an int. Did you use putBoolean while committing the value?

Comment: yes but now the problem that i have is that it always returns a false. Even when the checkbox is checked

Comment: In order for it to change, you would need to uncheck then check the checkbox. If the checkbox is  checked by default, then change the default in getBoolean to true. The reason for this is that shared pref is only updated when checkbox is changed.

Comment: the checkbox is not checked by default. And i've unchecked it and checked it . But still no change i always get a false.

Comment: Not sure what could go wrong in this simple code. Are the keys for putBoolean and getBoolean the same? You use "checkboxvalue". Make sure they are the same.

Comment: yes the keys are the same . Should i post my code to see if you can see where the error is?

Comment: OK. Try this. Instead of getPreferences, use 
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); Change on both fragment and activity

Comment: Yeah, I was being stupid. getPrefrences only work within single activity, while getSharedPreferences work across the app. I'll update my response. Please mark as answered. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using `interfaces`?

[Communicating between Fragments and Activities](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

The idea is that your activity implements an interface (e.g. `onRadioChecked()` ) and you will be able to detect that event in your activity, once the user checks the Check Box and of whatever you want there.

For handling the UI states between changes of Activity, read the link above.

Comment: i've used an interface for the communication between my configActivity and the fragment configFragment. the communication i need to do is between my two activites. I need to retrieve the value of "checking" variable

Comment: So you think it is not possible to implement an interface between two activities too? I am sure it is possible. If you need to retrieve it on Activity change, then you could use Bundle too. but if you need to do something with the value, then I'd go for the interface.